# Automating/scripting PAW requests, exporting responses

Tags: paw-app

I'd like to use `PAW` to hit the same service endpoint in different environments (ie. dev, staging, production), and then export the response to a text file so I can diff/compare responses.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to automate/script a .paw file containing my request(s)?
2. Is it then possible to export the response(s) to a text file?

Many thanks,

d.

Comment: this question is pretty unclear... can you be a little more specific? just about anything can be automated. do you mean you want to use an external tool to automate the creation of per-environment .paw files?

Comment: Hi, sorry if I was unclear.

What i want to do is to hit the same webpage on 3 different servers, and then log the responses to a text file (1 for each server). Ideally I'd like to be able to automate everything rather than having to open Paw manually.

Cheers,

d.

Comment: Sorry for late answer! Yes, you can write your own Code Generator (that will make Export available in this format), here's the doc: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Create_Code_Generator_Extension though for now you can only export like this request by request, and not batch export all...